# Alias, Group-by, Having

Tags: sql, group-by, difference, having

I'm very new to SQL. Would anyone be so kind as to explain whether there is any difference between these two queries?

```
SELECT author, sum(words) AS total_words
FROM books
GROUP BY author 
HAVING sum(words) > 10000000;

SELECT author, sum(words) AS total_words 
FROM books
GROUP BY author 
HAVING total_words > 10000000;
```

Comment: The second query is invalid. (However, some dbms products allow it anyway...)

Answer (score 0):

There is no substantive difference between the queries.  They should return exactly the same result set and have the same or substantially same execution plan.

One question is whether or not `sum(words)` is evaluated once or twice.  That probably depends on the database.  However, it is not hard for an optimizer to figure out that the expression should be calculated only once.  Even if it is calculated twice, the `sum()` is very cheap compared to the work needed for the `group by`.